# What are the motivations behind making true and false overloadable operators?

Tags: c#, .net

I asked this question on Stack Overflow and it was met with negative reception. I figured that Stack Overflow wasn't the right place to ask this question, so I decided to post it here.

Beside making types like `SqlBoolean` act more naturally, is there any other reason? If making three state boolean types is the only purpose of this decision, is it a good enough reason to add a feature that is so rarely used to a language?

Here's an example:

```
public class ThreeStateBool
{
    private bool? value;

    public ThreeStateBool(bool? value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static bool operator false(ThreeStateBool tsb)
    {
        return tsb.value == false;
    }

    public static bool operator true(ThreeStateBool tsb)
    {
        return tsb.value == true;
    }
}
```

Now that I've overloaded `true` and `false`, I can use this object in a conditional statement like:

```
if (new ThreeStateBool(false))
    Console.WriteLine("false");
else if (new ThreeStateBool(true))
    Console.WriteLine("true");
else if(new ThreeStateBool(null))
    Console.WriteLine("null");
```

Comment: The operators make three-state logic work more naturally.  As to whether the value of that was worth the effort, I suspect a lot of people would view a lot of language features as being silly relative to the features they feel the language should have but which are still missing.

Comment: Considering all the syntax hacks of LINQ to SQL, I wouldn't be surprised if Microsoft added this feature just to get better SQL support.

Answer (score 2):

You have to have a bit of context here: I think the main point missing is that this was a pre C#2.0 feature, which means it's a feature that came before nullable types. The [page that describes the overloading of the 'true' operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6y6z4d.aspx) is clearly geared towards the direction of having a nullable boolean without using a nullable type as support.

But there are other cases where you might want to treat an object instance as a boolean, for example where you want to check if the internal state of an object is ok, and you would want to write something C-style:

```
if (obj) {
    obj.DoSomething();
}
```

It's a possibility, it's not a mandatory thing that you'd want to do. It's a tool to be used if needed, and, as you well noted, it is somehow superseded by the use of nullable types; however, you might want to write something similar to a `ThreeStateBoolean` when you know, for example, that 'false' means 'null or false'. Writing those checks inline every time is a boring affair.

Comment: But that seems like a LOT of work for adding a feature that's not very useful. Is three state booleans the only reason ? I just can't get my head around it I guess.

Comment: I can't find any other reason; on the other hand, this feature was designed before nullable types.

Comment: Seems more like a hack than feature imo.

Comment: In the context of nullable types not being present, it's a pretty neat feature.

Comment: It's important to note that Unity does precisely this: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html